# Template Specializations and Static Locals

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, instantiation

I have a class X...

```
class X {...}
```

and I want to have one instance of X for each distinct type of some set of types.  (Some of these types are not classes and/or not written by me.)

To do this I thought of:

```
template<typename T> X& XT();
```

and then for each type A, B and C:

```
template<> X& XT<A>() { static X x; return x; }
template<> X& XT<B>() { static X x; return x; }
template<> X& XT<C>() { static X x; return x; }
```

Will this work? Is this the best way of doing it? What are some alternative ways?

Comment: That's pretty clever. I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: To me, question is still not clear.

Comment: In your mind, what does the word "local" refer to?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Local in scope, probably.

Comment: From the standard: "A variable declared at block scope is a _local variable_" C++11 3.3.3

Comment: @user1131467: I'm aware of this, but what you have isn't a block scope. Rather, it's a *class scope*. The notion of "local variable" doesn't really make sense there.

Comment: That is not correct.  XT is a function.  The X instances are block-scoped local variables with static storage duration.  These are called "local static variables" in the standard (3.7.1.3).  They are not class scoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specialize the function. You can simply do this:

```
template<typename T> 
X& XT() 
{ 
    static X x; 
    return x; 
}
```

And use it as:

```
X &xa = XT<A>();
X &xb = XT<B>();
X &xc = XT<C>();
X &xd = XT<A>(); //xd is same as xa
```

All three objects `xa`, `xb` and `xc` are different instances of X. However, `xa` and `xd` are same instances, as they both call the same function.

The point here to be noted is that the compiler instantiates different function for each different template argument. So `XT<A>()` is a different function than `XT<B>()`, and each function has its *own* `static` local variables. So the `static` local variable in `XT<A>()` is a different instance than the variable in `XT<B>()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to define each individually:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename X>
struct static_holder {
    static T static_instance;
};

template<typename T, typename X>
T static_holder<T,X>::static_instance;

template<typename T, typename X>
T &get_static_instance() {
    return static_holder<T,X>::static_instance;
}
```

Now you can just define:

```
template<typename K>
X &XT() {
    return get_static_instance<X, K>();
}
```

Note that this technique is likely to fail badly if used across shared library boundaries.

Comment: in linux it will work properly across shared library boundaries. I believe in windows you need to do something special with `dllexport` or something.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, I've had problems with this sort of thing across solibs - templates are fine, but you'll find that symbols don't get deduped. In my case it was RTTI information, but I suspect it would be the same with template statics too.